# filtering REQUEST_FILENAME in mod_rewrite for RewriteCond

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

First, a simple question. If this can't be done, I'll post a question seeking an alternative solution.

In a nutshell, I need some way to build a filtered file path for RewriteCond to check.

For example, I want to use this url: `/images/photos/gallery/beach.jpg/unique-identifier.jpg/width:50;height:50` to check whether this file: `/images/__resized/photos/gallery/beach.jpg/unique-indentifier.jpg` exists.

To make things more complicated, if this image file can't be found, I need to pass the full url to a resizer script that generates the resized image and finally sends a redirect header pointing to full url.

Please ask if you need more details. I left some intentionally out, since english isn't my first language and I felt adding more detail would make it harder to understand what I'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this rule will check if the filename is in your specific format. Then check if a file exists (adding __resized and omitting the last portion). If it does NOT exist then it will call `resizer.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^images/(.*)/width:[0-9]+;height:[0-9]+
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/__resized/%1 !-f
RewriteRule (.*) resizer.php
```

There is no need to give any GET parameters to the resizer script because it can access the *original URL* in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

You did not explicitly mention, but i guess if such file existed then you want to send it to the user.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^images/(.*)/width:[0-9]+;height:[0-9]+
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/__resized/%1 -f
RewriteRule (.*) /images/__resized/%1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Although it did not solve my problem, it made me realize that my line of thought was completely wrong :)

Comment: @Pichan Always glad to help :) Although, you can post an answer like "The problem can not be solved this way because ..." for others who try the same thing. Just a thought.

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow. Right now It's 3:26 and I'm still at the office working on this. The only problem left seems to be that I can't get the requested file relative to current dir to RewriteCond like I get with RewriteRule (.*)

Comment: @Pichan You can use `%{REQUEST_URI}` it's relative to current dir (if you are using *.htaccess*).

Comment: I'm using _.htaccess_ and `${REQUEST_URI}` seems to be relative to document root. I'm using apache2 on ubuntu 10.10.